# Can the M1 MBP drive a 4K display at 60Hz when not in clamshell mode?

Tags: display, 4k, apple-silicon

I have an M1 MBP. I connect it to my external display (DELL S2721QS) using a HyperDrive Viper hub.

When my MBP is in clamshell mode, the external display works at 4K 60Hz resolution. When the MBP is open, the external display only works at 4K 30Hz.

My hub and HDMI cable are both capable of 60Hz, as shown by the fact that it works when in clamshell mode. Does anyone know if the M1 MBP is capable of driving a 4K display at 60Hz when the laptop is open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is officially possible. Your MBP supports full native resolution on the internal display **in addition to** a single display up to 6K at 60 Hz.

To quote Apple's technical specifications:

> **Video Support**
>
> *Simultaneously* supports full native resolution on the
> built-in display in millions of colours *and* one external display with
> up to 6K resolution at 60Hz

<sup>[M1 MacBook Pro 13" - Technical Specifications](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-13/specs/)</sup>
<sup>Italics added for emphasis</sup>

As you can see, the specs specifically say: "Simultaneously supports".

Comment: Thanks Monomeeth, that's helpful. I'll investigate further and try with another USB-C hub.

Comment: Thanks again Monomeeth, I've now figured out the issue. I was using the built-in display at a scaled resolution - 1680 x 1050 - rather than the default - 1440 x 900. When using the default resolution for the internal display, I can have 4K60Hz on the external display with the laptop open.

Comment: That's great! :) I'm glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue with my M1 MBP 14" and Samsung U28E590D. Turns out the monitor has two HDMI ports but only one of them supports HDMI 2.0 (which is needed for 60 Hz). After plugging in to the correct port (with a HDMI 2.0 cable), I'm now getting maximum resolution both on the laptop (3024x1964@ProMotion) and the monitor (3840x2160@60Hz).

Btw I also tried the same setup with M1 MBA but couldn't get it past 30 Hz. A USB-C to DisplayPort cable works well at 4k@60, though.